# Turning Off ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents and ,DisplayAlerts

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the above code to Open an Excel file from a form. I'm trying to get the file open without the application request to update the Workbook links. But it seems for some reason whenever the file is open the application still popping up the message box asking whether or not to update the links of the workbook. Do you know why the code might not be working properly?
Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
```

`Dim RutaArchivo As String`

```
On Error Resume Next
RutaArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Test", _
                        filefilter:="Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
Workbooks.Open Filename:=RutaArchivo
With Application

.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use that to open the returned Workbook:

```
Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objexcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=RutaArchivo
objexcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thank very much you Stefan!, It's working just great!☺